# How many matches have there been at the top level which have ended up with a tied score and a winner?

Tags: records

In the current FIDE Grand Prix tournament in Jerusalem the [first round match between Pentala Harikrishna and Sergey Karjakin](https://chess24.com/en/watch/live-tournaments/jerusalem-fide-grand-prix-2019/1/6/9) ended in a tied score, 4.5-4.5, but Karjakin won because the last game was an armageddon game with him as black.

In the 1950's [Botvinnik "won" two world championship matches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Chess_Championship#FIDE_system_(1949%E2%80%931963)) as defending champion with a score of 12-12, one in 1951 against Bronstein and again in 1954 against Smyslov. At the time there were no tie-breaks for world championship matches. Instead the defending champion retained the title.

That makes 3 matches. Are there any more?

Comment: Speaking of world championship matches: Kasparov - Karpov 1987, the 4th installment of their rivalry saw Kasparov win Game 24 to retain his title 12-12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Remellion pointed out, the [1987 Kasparov - Karpov world championship match](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chess.pl?tid=55128) also finished in a tie, 12-12, with Kasparov retaining the title.

That chessgames.com link leads on to the 1910 Lasker vs Schlechter world championship match that finished 5-5 with Lasker retaining the title. The interesting story of the match is told [here](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chess.pl?tid=54100). With one game to play Schlechter was leading 5-4 and only needed a draw to become world champion. Instead of playing safe he played for the win but after a game lasting 11 hours spread over 3 days he lost and Lasker retained the title.

Another tied game which had a winner was the [1983 Smyslov - Hübner Candidates Quarterfinal Match](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chess.pl?tid=87187) which ended 5-5 and then was extended with 4 full length tie-break games (all draws) for a final score of 7-7.

The match was held in Velden, Austria, about 500 meters from the Casino Velden and so to decide the winner they used the roulette wheel. If the ball fell into a black number Hübner would be the winner and if red then Smyslov. The first spin saw the ball end up in zero (no colour) so a second spin was needed which landed in red, so Smyslov won the match.

Robert Byrne, [reporting in the New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/1983/05/08/arts/chess-should-chance-decide-the-outcome-of-a-match.html), thought this was very unfair and proposed that more rapid games should be used to break ties when the tie-break games at the regular time control failed to produce a winner. Perhaps this was the first time rapid games had been suggested as a tie-break mechanism?

So, that takes the total up to 6.

Comment: Kramnik-Leko 2004

Comment: There is a theory that Schlecter played for a win because he needed to win by 2 points in order to win that title. Kasparov in OMGP is supporting that theory.